# difference between getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("fr", "FR")) and getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE)

Tags: java

Can you explain the difference between these two options?

```
getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("fr", "FR"))
getCurrencyInstance(Locale.FRANCE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see any difference in the code.

Locale.FRANCE is defined as Locale("fr","FR") in the end. In the end those constants are there just to make our lives easier.